# Remote Desktop only worked the first time and doesn't work anymore

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, remote, windows-server-2012

I am trying to RDP into a server I have connected to the router in my house from my laptop. I am on the same network as the server. Yesterday, I tried using a linux client to connect to it. The very first try worked after giving me the usual certificate warnings and I saw the server loading up and such. I went afk for a few minutes and came back to see I couldn't actually manipulate the server even though it was connected. I thought the RDP client crashed so I closed it and re-opened it to try again but it hasn't connected since. I can ping it no problem but I can't get it to connect at all. The server has previously been used via RDP so it is definitely enabled. Any help would be appreciated as I need to prepare the server for an upcoming LAN event this weekend.

Comment: It's possibly left your the RDP account logged in. Can you access the server directly? Can you look at the currently logged in users via Task Manager?

Comment: Do you get any message when you try to log on?

Comment: I'm going to hook up a monitor to it today and see what is going on. It does not give me a message, just the usual "Could not establish connection because 1).... 2).... 3)....". I also trier restarting the server manually but that didn't work.

Comment: It seems my friend who dropped off the server forgot to leave the dvi cable and the server doesn't have a vga port. I don't have a dvi cable as of now. Is there anything I can try software wise before I can hook up a monitor to this thing?

Comment: Ok I hooked up a monitor. It's running Windows Server 2012 R2. The users tab in task manager indicates that Administrator is logged but it has a '(7)'. If I expand it, the following are shown as logged on: 

Client Server Runtime Process,
Desktop Window Manager,
Host Process for Windows Tasks,
Server Manager,
Task Manager,
Windows Explorer,
Windows Logon Application.

Are any of these related to RDP?

Comment: I figured it out. The Hyper -V Manager on the server has about 9 different VM's which also run Windows Server 2012 R2. I turned one of them on, and tried to RDP into it and worked. Thought this was weird so I tried emulating what I remember I did when I closed it the one time it worked. It still worked when I tried to connect to it again. In the end it turned out to be that the firewall was on, on the main server and that was not letting the connection through. Firewall was off for private networks, but on for public ones.